# How to retrieve header values from SOAP Envelope in Spring WS

Tags: java, spring-ws

I am getting some values in SOAPHeader in a Spring Webservice. I would like to retrieve those values .

Comment: Is this on the client or server?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with using

```
  SOAPHeader soapHeader = message.getSOAPHeader();
  Iterator elements = soapHeader.getChildElements();
```

Do we talk about SAAJ?

Comment: Yes i am using SAAJSoapMessage

Comment: So did you try getChildElements?